# ¿Como puedo excluir un componente de un Layout en ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

Me explico: tengo una estructura de rutas en **ReactJS** de la siguiente forma:

```
<BrowserRouter>
    <Layout header={ this.state.header } navbar={ this.state.navbar }>
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" render={ () => <Dashboard items={ this.state.navbar.items } /> }/>
            <Route exact path="/panel" component={ Panel } />
        </Switch>
    </Layout>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Como se ve en el código cualquier ruta que agregue ejecutará el componente indicado y lo pintará utilizando el `Layout` ya definido. Mi pregunta es ¿Como puedo decirle a una de esas rutas que ignore el `Layout`? Es decir que no muestre nada del contenido del `Layout`.

Una solución que se me ocurrió fue indicar por cada `Route` el `Layout` a pintar pero no se si sea la manera correcta de hacerlo.

```
<BrowserRouter>
    <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" render={ () => <Dashboard items={ this.state.navbar.items } /> } }/>

        <Route exact path="/panelcem" render={ () => {
            return(
                <Layout header={ this.state.header } navbar={ this.state.navbar }>
                    <PanelCem />
                </Layout>
            )
        } } />
    </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes intentar pasar una prop que diga al layout si renderiza o no.

```
<Layout hasToBeRendered={true} />
```

Otra opción es simplemente no pintar el componente, ¿estás obligado a pintarlo incluso si no necesitas mostrar nada?

Comment: El problema es que para pasar ese prop me toca indicar por cada Route el Layout, que es lo que ya estoy haciendo y no me parece óptimo. El componente si va a mostrar información solo no necesita lo que contiene el Layout

Comment: Mira a ver si esto que comentan aquí soluciona tu pregunta https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57572051/ignore-react-router-route